# How can I declare a mixin method such that it's usable from both instance methods and class methods?

Tags: ruby, module, mixins

I want to put a method in a Ruby module such that it can be called from a class method *or* an instance method, using simple syntax:

```
module MyMod
  def fmt *args
    args.map { | a | "You said #{a}" }
  end
end

class MyClass
  include MyMod
  def inst
    puts fmt 1,2,3
  end
  def self.cls
    puts fmt 4,5,6
  end
end
```

The above doesn't work because the class method (`cls`) can't see the instance method fmt.  If I change the definition to `self.fmt`, then the instance method has to invoke it as `MyMod.fmt`.

I'd like to be able to just invoke `fmt (some stuff)` from both types of method.  Is there a "ruby-ish" way of doing this?  I can define the module as

```
module MyMod
  def self.fmt *args
    args.map { | a | "You said #{a}" }
  end
  def fmt *args
    MyMod.fmt args
  end
end
```

but that's not very DRY, is it?  Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use advantage of `Module#included` method to do it like that:

```
module MyMod
  # here base is a class the module is included into
  def self.included(base)
    # extend includes all methods of the module as class methods
    # into the target class
    base.extend self
  end

  def fmt(*args)
    args.map { |a| "You said #{a}" }
  end
end

class MyClass
  # regular include provides us with instance methods
  # and defined above MyMod#included hook - with class methods
  include MyMod

  def inst
    puts fmt(1, 2, 3)
  end

  def self.cls
    puts fmt(4, 5, 6)
  end
end

puts MyClass.cls
puts MyClass.new.inst
```

And here's the output:

```
You said 4
You said 5
You said 6

You said 1
You said 2
You said 3
```

For more detailed explanation have a look at [this article](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/).

Comment: That callback is fine when building something that acts as a kind of DSL that other developers should include into their classes. Otherwise this is a bit too much magic to be justified, as it is not instantly clear that using `include` will result in class methods being added. So if this is in internal code it's almost always of benefit to manually use `extend` itself, instead of going through the hassle of documenting that special behaviour.

Comment: Good point, but if you want to use this module in multiple places I don't think calling both `include` and `extend` wherever you need it is a good solution.

Comment: @KL-7, why not?  The module is doing that for you... you don't have to do it.  It's the only way anyway.

Comment: That's exactly what we're discussing though, whether the module should be "doing that for you" or not. And that it's "the only way" is obviously wrong as there's still the "manual" way…

Comment: Totally missed the first comment, sorry ;)

Comment: I'm going to take your advice with a tiny caveat... Your post helped me understand some stuff I had found elsewhere online.  It suggested having an internal class, inside the "helper" class, which has all the methods I want to use as class methods.  Then, you use `base.extend TheInternalClass` instead of `base.extend self`, such that only the internal class's methods are added as class methods.  That addresses the concern about being "dangerous" to add too many at once.

Comment: Yes, that's a very common approach, but usually it's `ClassMethods` inner module, not class.

Answer (score 1):

Both `include` and `extend`the `MyMod` module in `MyClass`, so that the `fmt` method gets added both as an instance and a class method to `MyClass`.

What `Object#extend` does is add the methods of a module to a single instance. In this case, that instance is the class itself, which is why the methods will be available as class methods.